# How to put 4 photos in one slide in beamer with captions on sides

Tags: beamer, subfloats

I have 4 photos and I wanna put those in 2*2 form. Unfortunately, those photos do not fit the page. I am thinking about some approaches to handle it.

1. How is it possible to decrease the vertical distance between photos?
2. How is it possible to put the caption of each photo on either left or right sides such that photos fit the page?
3. How to decrease the margin on the top and bottom of the slide?

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5em}{-1.5em}
\scriptsize
\begin{figure}[H]   \centering
    \subfloat[\scriptsize Objective function]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{pic/Disobjective.pdf}\label{fig:figure6-1}} 
    %\quad
\subfloat[\scriptsize Improvement]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{pic/Disrandomzied_improvement.pdf} \label{fig:figure6-6}}   \quad
    \subfloat[\scriptsize Quantity]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{pic/Disquantity.pdf} \label{fig:figure6-2}}        
    \subfloat[\centering \scriptsize Probability ]{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{pic/Disalpha.pdf} \label{fig:figure6-4}}    
\label{fig:figure6}
\end{figure}
\end{adjustwidth}
''

Thanks
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example so we can see which theme you use, how big the margins of this theme are and what size your images have?

Comment: ... and can you please have a look at the comments to your previous question? It would be nice if you could answer the points to clarify some details

Comment: Assuming you don't want to shrink your images, we need to know their size.  You can do than using `\sbox0{\includegraphics{...}}\the\wd0\quad\the\ht0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the whole `\linewidth` except for small gaps between the captions and the photos.

I used top aligned captions, but center aligned or bottom aligned captions are actually easier to do.

I take it that numberless captions are normal with beamer?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for valign

\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
\abovecaptionskip=0pt
\sbox0{\includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=T]{example-image-a}}%
\sbox1{\includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=T]{example-image-b}}%
\setlength{\tempdima}{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd0-\wd1-2\tabcolsep}%
\divide\tempdima by 2
\begin{minipage}[t]{\tempdima}
  \caption{First photo}
\end{minipage}\hfill\usebox0\usebox1\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\tempdima}
  \caption{Second photo}
\end{minipage}

\sbox0{\includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=T]{example-image-c}}%
\sbox1{\includegraphics[scale=0.3, valign=T]{example-image}}%
\setlength{\tempdima}{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd0-\wd1-2\tabcolsep}%
\divide\tempdima by 2
\begin{minipage}[t]{\tempdima}
\caption{Third photo}
\end{minipage}\hfill\usebox0\usebox1\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\tempdima}
\caption{4th photo}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks. It is great

Answer (score 3):

You need no `figure` environment and no `\subfloat`, just a tabular.

Let's choose to divide the text width into six parts, the images will be worth two parts. Actually, to allow for some padding between captions and photos, I'll use 15% of the text width for each part.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}% no padding at the left
  >{\raggedright}p{0.15\textwidth}% left captions
  @{\hspace{0.05\textwidth}}
  c@{}c% the images
  @{\hspace{0.05\textwidth}}
  >{\raggedright}p{0.15\textwidth}% right captions
  @{}% no padding
}
First photo &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
Second photo \tabularnewline
Third photo &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image} &
Fourth photo \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much